# How to edit and save html file with firefox addon

Tags: file, save, firefox-addon

I am developing a firefox addon with jpm.
my addon has a button and when I click this , a HTML page load in screen as popup.now in this popup I have 2 text input and a button that I named it "save".I want to when I click in this button the data in these text input save in HTML file.What I must to do?

Comment: Effectively your question could be paraphrased as: "Here is my (not clearly stated) idea, write my code for me." As such it is too broad for this format. Please see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: You can use the file i/o module - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_file

Comment: Thanks . in this link there are no function for write in file . there are some function about read or open file .